# How to SUM each row in a Range in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Attendance spreadsheet where I need to SUM a row and have the totals in the last columns. Each row represents an employee and each column represents a day in the month. The reason I am using VBA is because some date columns will contain text, such as TA for Tardy and need to add 0.5 to the total if TA is present in one or more of the cells in the range.

I can only get the first row to populate, but not the rows below it. I am guessing it is because I am not setting my ranges correctly. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Dim wsJAN As Worksheet      'Used to reference the sheet by its TAB name in the WB
Dim LastRow As Long         'Last used row on sheet
Dim tDays As Range          'Total # of days the employee has actually worked
Dim cDays As Range          'Current # of days the employee should have worked
Dim rowEmployee As Range    'Used to define the columns to be used to when adding attendance for each employee row
Dim rCell As Range

LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A3], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsJAN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JAN")
Set tDays = wsJAN.Range("AG3")
Set cDays = wsJAN.Range("AH3")
Set rowEmployee = wsJAN.Range("B3:AF3")

tDays = "=SUM(B3:AF3)"
cDays = "=SUM(B3:AF3)"

For Each rCell In rowEmployee
If rCell.Value = "TA" Then

    tDays = tDays + 0.5    ' Add only a half day to the # of days the employee has worked in Column AG if tardy.
    cDays = cDays + 1      ' Add a whole day to current days worked in Column AH if employee is tardy.
End If
Next


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I have even tried using For i = 1 To LastRow Step 1 around the For Each loop and Do.....Loop Until LastRow with out any success. My rows will always start at row 3 so I need something along the lines of :

AG3 =SUM(B3:AF3)
AG4 =SUM(B4:AF4)

Down to the last row

Comment: Are your columns Fixed? i.e `B` to `AF`? In other words, is the total always in Col `AG`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using two loops instead of one - to sum in cols and in rows. For me the easiest way to run through such a regular sheet is to use Offset for the given range. Here's the solution:

```
Dim wsJAN As Worksheet      'Used to reference the sheet by its TAB name in the WB
Dim LastRow As Long         'Last used row on sheet
Dim tDays As Double          'Total # of days the employee has actually worked
Dim cDays As Integer          'Current # of days the employee should have worked
Dim rowEmployee As Range    'Used to define the columns to be used to when adding attendance for each employee row
Dim rCell As Range
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsJAN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JAN")
Set rowEmployee = wsJAN.Range("B3:AF3")

i = 0
Do While Range("B3").Offset(i).Value <> Empty        ' for each row
    tDays = 0
    cDays = 0
    For Each rCell In rowEmployee          ' for each column
        If rCell.Offset(i).Value = "TA" Then
            tDays = tDays + 0.5    ' Add only a half day to the # of days the employee has worked in Column AG if tardy.
            cDays = cDays + 1      ' Add a whole day to current days worked in Column AH if employee is tardy.
        End If
    Next
    ' set AG as tDays && AH as cDays
    Range("AG3").Offset(i).Value = tDays
    Range("AH3").Offset(i).Value = cDays
    i = i + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Now it counts the TA-s only (your IF statement says so), but you can now easily modify it, to count whatever is needed.

Comment: Makciook - your VBA worked perfectly!!! I just needed modify my IF statements to account for all text variables.

Answer (score 2):

> add 0.5 to the total if TA is present in one or more of the cells in the range.

I am confused. Do you want to add .5 for every "TA" or just once if a TA is found. If it is just once then see `PART A` else See `PART B` below

**PART A**

Do you need VBA for this? If your columns are fixed i.e `B` to `AF` and your `total` is always in Col `AG` then this can be achieved with a simple Excel Formula.

Just enter this formula in Cell `AG3` and copy it down

```
=SUM(B3:AF3) + IF(COUNTIF(A3:AF3,"TA")>0,0.5,0)
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

If you still want VBA then you can try this as well

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long

    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Assuming that the names are in col A
        LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("AG3:AG" & LRow).Formula = "=SUM(B3:AF3) + IF(COUNTIF(A3:AF3,""TA"")>0,0.5,0)"
    End With
End Sub
```

**PART B**

```
=SUM(B3:AF3)+COUNTIF(A3:AF3,"TA")*0.5
```

Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long

    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Assuming that the names are in col A
        LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("AG3:AG" & LRow).Formula = "=SUM(B3:AF3)+COUNTIF(A3:AF3,""TA"")*0.5"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddarth - I tried using your VBA code in Part B, but it was giving me a Compile error: Syntax Error on ".Range("AG3:AG" & LRow).Formula = "=SUM(B3:AF3)+COUNTIF(A3:AF3,"TA")*0.5". And I do you more than one variable to SUM and I wasn't sure how to concatenate your Formula.